# How do I make one Java thread return before some of its child threads finish?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 nested threads.

First thread starts multiple instances of second thread. Each second thread has to sleep for some time (5 seconds).

I want to start the first thread and return a message to user immediately, but it seems my first thread waits until all the children of second thread to finish.

How can I achieve this? Any help?

Comment: The code you're using would probably help.

Comment: You are calling `Thread.run` instead of `Thread.start` are you? That's a very common mistake (and a result of bad design of `Thread`).

Comment: Hi Tom,

Thanks for the response.

Here is how my code looks.

FirstThread.run();

In run method of first thread, I am running multiple second threads as:

SecondThread.run();
SecondThread.sleep(5000);

I want my first thread to return immediately rather than waiting for all second thread childs to finish.

You advise to use 'start' on first thread or second thread?

Thanks again.

Comment: ...put the code into the question please (and delete the comment...)

Comment: Hi Tom,

Thank you. I replaced 'run' with 'start' in both first thread and second thread.

It works fine now.

Thanks to all who responded with valueble suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

There are some common mistakes when dealing with `java.lang.Thread`.

- Calling `run` on the thread instead of `start`. This is nothing magical about the `run` method.
- Calling static methods on thread instances. Unfortunately this compiles. A common example is `Thread.sleep`. `sleep` is a static method and will always sleep the current thread, even if the code appears to be calling it on a different thread.

Rather than dealing with threads directly it is generally better to use a thread pool from `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 1):

What you should probably do, is create a single thread pool via `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`.  From your main thread `submit` Runnables (tasks) to the pool.  Return to your main thread a list of `Future`s.

In Java there exists enough framework code that one rarely should need to deal with threads directly.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to see code. It depends on where you are putting `Thread.sleep();`.

Answer (score 0):

Like someone else has pointed out with Threads you call start() which is a non-blocking call and actually gets the thread rolling. Calling run() will block until the run() method finishes. See the example code below;

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstThread firstThread = new FirstThread();
        firstThread.start();
        System.out.println("Main Method ending");
    }
}


public class FirstThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            SecondThread secondThread = new SecondThread(i);
            secondThread.start();
        }
        System.out.println("FirstThread is finishing");
    }
}

public class SecondThread extends Thread {

    private int i;

    public SecondThread(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Second thread number " + i + " doing stuff here...");
            // Do stuff here...

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000); 
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                //ignore for sleeping}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the output:

```
Main Method ending
Second thread number 0 doing stuff here...
Second thread number 1 doing stuff here...
FirstThread is finishing
Second thread number 2 doing stuff here...
Second thread number 0 doing stuff here...
Second thread number 2 doing stuff here...
Second thread number 1 doing stuff here...
```

Comment: BTW - I suspect you don't actually need a class called "FirstThread" - you can probably just launch the SecondThread instances from your main Thread.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced 'run' with 'start' in both first thread and second thread. 
It works fine now.

Thanks to all who responded with valueble suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FirstThread extends Thread {

    public synchronized void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("i="+i);
        }
        System.out.println("FirstThread is finishing");
    }
}

public class SecondThread extends Thread {

    public synchronized void run() {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("j="+j);
        }
        System.out.println("Second Thread is finishing");
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstThread firstThread = new FirstThread();
        SecondThread a=new SecondThread()
        firstThread.start();
        a.start();

    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
i=0
i=1
i=2
i=3
FirstThread is finishing

j=0
j=1
j=2
j=3
Second Thread is finishing
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Synchronized` keyword which will use to run one thread completely

example

```
public synchronized void run() //which thread to run completely
{
}
```